# How to see duplicate http headers in Dart

Tags: dart, http, cookies, header

So I'm scraping a webpage with authentication, meaning I need to consume the Set-Cookie header. This website, however, sends a response with 2 Set-Cookie headers, but as headers are served as a Map, duplicates can't exist. This means I'm only able to consume the first Set-Cookie header.

I have tried stock Dart:io http lib, dio, http, and requests library. Neither provides a way to consume headers in shape of something else than a Map.

Comment: If you use the `HttpClient` from Dart itself, it does not serve your headers as a `Map` but instead as an object of the `HttpHeaders` class: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.0.7/dart-io/HttpHeaders-class.html . It allows for having multiple values for a given field.